# Scrolling to the Previously Selected ListBox item

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am having trouble setting the Selected Item of a Listbox I am populating and adding to the `LayoutRoot`'s children in code.

I am creating the `ListBox` over when going back to the page, so I am saving a variable which will tell me what the selected item was before the user clicked.

I tried setting `SelectedIndex`, but that did not seem to work. That selects the item and calls SelectionChanged, but the item does not come into focus.

I also tried the combination of  `MyListBox.ScrollIntoView(MyListBox.Items[MyListBox.SelectedIndex])` and `MyListBox.UpdateLayout()`, but that did not seem to work either. The item does not seem to come into focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this by Adding the UserControl that had the ListBox into the Page's XAML, and the ListBox into the UserControl's XAML.

Then, I was able to use the `ScrollIntoView(MyListBox.Items[mySavedSelectedItem]);`

I simply saved this value when the user made the selection.

```
mySavedSelectedItem = ((ListBox)sender).SelectedIndex;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `MyListBox.SelectedItem.EnsureVisible()`.

(If it doesn't have `SelectedItem` (`ListBox` on the desktop CLR doesn't), then use `SelectedItems[0]` instead)

E: Okay, looks like Windows Phone doesn't support that. However, it does support `MyListBox.EnsureVisible(MyListBox.SelectedItems[0])`

Comment: That function does not appear to be available in Windows Phone 7.

Comment: My bad. I've updated my answer, now that I had a chance to look at the docs.

Comment: That doesn't appear to be available either.

Comment: Are you sure? According to the documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.ensurevisible%28VS.90%29.aspx), it's available on ".NET Compact Framework Supported in: 3.5, 2.0, 1.0". If you switch to .NET 4 (since I don't know what version the phone uses), it adds "4 and 3.5 SP1"

Comment: Just to be clear, are we talking about `EnsureVisible` or `SelectedItems`?

Comment: EnsureVisible. SelectedItems is available.